# How to commit a URL substituting a file into a git repository?

Tags: git

Is there a way to commit a user-specified URL into a git repository, as a substitute for a file? The worktree would have the "actual" file, but it shouldn't get into the .git-directory and therefore would not be pushed.

To illustrate / give a usecase: For a hardware project, I'd like to add a datasheet to a repository - I don't have the right to redistribute it. But commonly, datasheets are publicly available on a (hopefully) fixed URL and are not changed by the project they're used for. Substituting the file for the URL pointing to the datasheet from the vendor would avoid the legal redistribution problem. git-LFS doesn't fit the bill since as a user I can't point to an existing URL.

Comment: This is just what Git-LFS does. (Except that it tries to store a copy of the file on the LFS server, rather than use some existing URL—but the general idea is the same.)

Comment: Right. I actually read up on git-LFS just before posting this question and concluded that it doesn't really fit here, because you still need distribution rights AFAIU. I clarified the question.

Answer (score 0):

> To illustrate / give a usecase: For a hardware project, I'd like to add a datasheet to a repository - I don't have the right to redistribute it. But commonly, datasheets are publicly available on a (hopefully) fixed URL.

That's either a smudge filter or a post-checkout hook.  But, really, for a use case like this, it's almost always better to just commit the url and let users fetch it themselves with curl or their browser of choice, or however they keep their boats afloat.  Repositories are user-administered, you can't set up automated processing like what you're after without user intervention or code injection, and Git does not do code injection.

You could ship a sample "fetch-datasheets" command and show them how to install it as a post-checkout hook, but how much time are you really talking about spending and saving here? `` open `cat datasheet.url` `` or `` open `jq -r .url datasheet.url` `` seems like less to ask of your users than setting up git hooks to do the same task willy-nilly.